# Data cannot be saved into database(Spring MVC+Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I want to save BranchID in the database. All the values are inserted into the database but branchId cannot be saved. Can Anyone help with this?

Here is the code:

#### Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCreatePage(Model model,Principal principal){
        //model.addAttribute(new UserEntity());
        model.addAttribute("body", "user/user-create-temp");
        model.addAttribute("userInit", userService.getGeneralInfo(principal));
        return "layouts/default";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showCreateUser(Model model, @Valid GeneralDto userEntity,BindingResult result) {


        userService.saveUser(userEntity.getUserEntity());

        return "redirect:/user/list";
    }
```

#### GeneralDto:

```
public class GeneralDto {
    private List<BranchEntity> branchEntities = new ArrayList<BranchEntity>();
    private UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity();


    public UserEntity getUserEntity() {
        return userEntity;
    }

    public void setUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
        this.userEntity = userEntity;
    }

    public List<BranchEntity> getBranchEntities() {
        return branchEntities;
    }

    public void setBranchEntities(List<BranchEntity> branchEntities) {
        this.branchEntities = branchEntities;
    }

}
```

ThemeLeaf Form:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/user/create}"
    method="post" th:object="${userInit}" onsubmit="return validatePassword()">
    <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group form-group-code">
            <label for="code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="hidden" th:field="*{userEntity.userId}"></input> 
                <input type="text" th:field="*{userEntity.username}" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Username"></input>
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userEntity.username')}">
                    <label th:errors="*{userEntity.username}" style="color: red"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full name</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text"  th:field="*{userEntity.fullName}" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Fullname"></input>
                               <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userEntity.fullName')}">
                            <label th:errors="*{userEntity.fullName}"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" th:field="*{userEntity.email}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email"></input>
                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userEntity.email')}">
                            <label th:errors="*{userEntity.email}"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{userEntity.password}" th:id="password" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Password"></input>


                    </div>
                </div> 
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password"></input>

                     </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Branch </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select class="form-control"
                                        th:field="*{branchEntities}">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="">Select
                                            Branch</option>
                                        <option th:each="branch : *{branchEntities}"
                                            th:value="${branch.branchId}"
                                            th:text="${branch.branchName}"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                  <!-- <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label>Active
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{enabled}" value="" name="enabled" class="flat-red" checked="checked"></input>
                        </label>
                        <label>Inactive
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{enabled}" th:value="${userEntity.userId}" name="enabled" class="flat-red"></input>
                        </label>
                        </div>


                </div>  --> 

        <div></div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
         <button th:if="${userInit.userEntity.userId == null}"
            type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Submit</button> 
        <button th:if="${userInit.userEntity.userId != null}"
            type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Update</button> 
        <a th:href="@{/users}" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it looks. I think it would be better for you to use `branchId` in your `GeneralDto` instead of `branchEntities` send the `branchEntities` via `model.addAttribute("userInit",branchEntities);`
and show it to your drop down.
And receive your `branchId` in your `GeneralDto`.

Answer (score 0):

in best practice when you add @Valid annotation beside any class always handle the errors.like`if(result.hasErrors()){
//do someething}`.
the problem is in your `private List<BranchEntity> branchEntities = new ArrayList<BranchEntity>();`
here, you are adding a list but user can't be in many branches. see the mapping of your branch and user table.